# To find deezer API artwork through echo PHP

Tags: javascript, php, echo

I found here in the forum this code php and I tried to adapt to what I intend, in [this link](https://api.deezer.com/2.0/search?q=sam%20smith) there is a JSON where they have information about the artist that we search. But I want to extract only this function `cover_xl`

```js
"cover_xl":"https:\/\/cdns-images.dzcdn.net\/images\/cover\/1c7a7c081a1e7787321f81a889e9f7b8\/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg"
```

I've been trying in many ways but with no result, so I've come to ask for your help. I also leave the code to try to help in the resolution.

```js
<?php 
    $query = 'https://api.deezer.com/2.0/search?q=sam smith'; 
    $file = file_get_contents($query); 
    $parsedFile = json_decode($file); 
    $albumart = $parsedFile->data[0]->artist->picture[cover_xl]; 
?>
```

Comment: What do you want to retrieve? The artist's picture or the first album cover you find?

Comment: @karliwson What I want to remove from the function is inside the picture more properly (cover_xl) https:\/\/cdns-images.dzcdn.net\/images\/cover\/1c7a7c081a1e7787321f81a889e9f7b8\/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand. Do you mean extract the image (instead of 'remove')? Please try to explain it better.

Comment: @karliwson It does not hurt and I appreciate your help. I want to extract from the function that is referenced in [$ query] the image designated by [cover_xl] in which I gave the link, through echo php.

Comment: Isn't it just a typo? `$parsedFile->data[0]->artist->picture['cover_xl']` -> note the single quotes around `cover_xl`

Comment: @giorgio I tried to modify the code with its modifications and a blank page appears, is the code well worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following code I did what you want:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://api.deezer.com/2.0/search?q=sam%20smith';
$jsonStr = file_get_contents($url);
$jsonArr = json_decode($jsonStr, true);

$coverXlCollection = array();

foreach ($jsonArr['data'] as $row) {
    $coverXlCollection[] = $row['album']['cover_xl'];
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($coverXlCollection, true).'</pre>';

?>
```

And the result is as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/231c66c0ed260c708163eff3bb8458da/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [1] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/231c66c0ed260c708163eff3bb8458da/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [2] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/231c66c0ed260c708163eff3bb8458da/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [3] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/231c66c0ed260c708163eff3bb8458da/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [4] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/5ef4779d20ab952d346e185f3b1dbce7/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [5] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/231c66c0ed260c708163eff3bb8458da/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [6] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/75e56110a5cef30a4518a075d10ad05e/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [7] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/231c66c0ed260c708163eff3bb8458da/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [8] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/e44468007c45f2523d056a0b19eed80a/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [9] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/231c66c0ed260c708163eff3bb8458da/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [10] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/231c66c0ed260c708163eff3bb8458da/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [11] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/b962a96a59b95fd1c571e911a9548736/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [12] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/231c66c0ed260c708163eff3bb8458da/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [13] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/231c66c0ed260c708163eff3bb8458da/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [14] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/305b58c95901abbe0caa4060ce010402/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [15] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/231c66c0ed260c708163eff3bb8458da/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [16] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/2a9aa91b1a681f1b34a313ef9fb73740/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [17] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/231c66c0ed260c708163eff3bb8458da/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [18] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/231c66c0ed260c708163eff3bb8458da/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [19] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/231c66c0ed260c708163eff3bb8458da/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [20] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/7029607d87e45f2f48b8e5686a94d20a/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [21] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/80b66c217a1711b7aa9ad7fb37bee8b8/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [22] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/a073bd9a28dd2ef46c4014ff3968545a/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [23] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/a073bd9a28dd2ef46c4014ff3968545a/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
    [24] => https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/a073bd9a28dd2ef46c4014ff3968545a/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg
)
```

I did a few modifications of your code and I used `json_decode()` function with second parameter `true`. In this case you have the result as array instead of object.

Cheers.

Comment: Everything is very good of your code, what I only intend is the [0] => that is inside the array, I already tried to add this formula in the code but it gives error, could you help me? Thank you!

Comment: @Andy Cruz what error do you get. Could you provide some code ?

Comment: `$jsonArr['data'][0]['album']['cover_xl']` this is how you should access the first element

Comment: I made this change but it still appears all the links or so it's me that I put in the wrong place. Could I make the total alteration so that I could try to figure out how to do it and get there? Thank you for your help

Comment: Simply after this row `$jsonArr = json_decode($jsonStr, true);` put this code `echo $jsonArr['data'][0]['album']['cover_xl'];` and you should see only the first link

Comment: I had not put the echo before the function, thank you very much for your help sand, without you I had not been able to solve my problem. Thank you so much for everything.
Cheers!